# How to execute code once when reaching a value and continue looping until next value is reached?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I have a list of floats `listItemPos` and another floats being updated each frame `playPosition`.

I am trying to execute a piece of code each time `playPosition` passes above one of the values in `listItemPos`.

This is what my code looks like :

```
listItemPos.sort() #sort the item positions

# This is the loop being called each frame:

for x in range(0, len(listItemPos)):                
  if playPosition >= listItemPos[x]: 
    print("I passed item number " + str(x))
    """
    This is where I would like to have a function execute only once 
    when reaching one of the value of my list.
    """
```

As of now, and as expected, I have an incrementation of prints each frame each time a value of my list is passed.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have multiple values you want to stop for, have a look at this:

```
import numpy as np
listItemPos.sort() #sort the item positions

# The values you want to stop for (numpy so we can do fancy filtering)
stopvalues = np.array([4,8,32])

# This is the loop being called each frame:

for x in range(0, len(listItemPos)):                
  if playPosition >= listItemPos[x]: 
    print("I passed item number " + str(x))
    if x in stopvalues:
        executeFunc()
    # so its executed once, remove the corresponding value:
        stopvalues = stopvalues[[stopvalues != x]]
```

Comment: That do well ! Thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help you out. Please dont forget to mark an answer as accepted and upvote those answers, that helped you with your case

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
listItemPos.sort() #sort the item positions

target = 2 # use a target flag

for x in range(0, len(listItemPos)):                
  if playPosition >= listItemPos[x]: 
    print("I passed item number " + str(x))
    if listItemPos[x] == target:
       func()
       target = None # remove the target
```